# Selected file image in a bottomsheet form does not display immediately until I tap a field in the form

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm having a little challenge displaying selected file image in a bottomSheet form. The image simply doesn't display immediately until I tap any field in the form, then the image shows. I'm not sure what's causing this if it is because the form is outside scaffold or what? I want the image to display as soon as it is picked.

Below is what the form widget looks like.

//Form is outside scaffold

```
Widget bottomSheetSeller() {
    return Form(
      key: formKey,
      onChanged: () => setState(() => value = value),
      child: Container(
        height: 400,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 20.0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 4.0,
                width: 50.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: globalDefault,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 45.0),
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  'Seller Form',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    fontSize: globalHeading,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 25.0),
              FormWithValidation(
                  initialValue: value,
                  hint: 'First Name',
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  validate: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty) {
                      return "fill this field";
                    } else if (value.length <= 2) {
                      return "too short!";
                    } else {
                      return null;
                    }
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) => setState(() => firstName = value!)),

              const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              FormWithValidation(
                  initialValue: value,
                  hint: 'Last Name',
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  validate: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty) {
                      return "fill this field";
                    } else if (value.length <= 2) {
                      return "too short!";
                    } else {
                      return null;
                    }
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) => setState(() => lastName = value!)),
              const SizedBox(height: 15.0),

              //File upload
              Container(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    yourLogo.isEmpty
                        ? TextButton(
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                              padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                  const EdgeInsets.all(15)),
                              side: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                BorderSide(
                                    width: 1,
                                    color: globalInfoColor,
                                    style: BorderStyle.solid),
                              ),
                              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () async {
                              selectImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                            },
                            child: Unicon(
                              Unicons.uniPlus,
                              size: bigHeader,
                              color: globalInfoColor,
                            ),
                          )
                        : setPicture(),
                    const SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                    const Text('Company logo'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Allowed image format: jpg, jpeg, png',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: globalInfoColor,
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              const SizedBox(height: 30.0),
              ButtonWidget(),
```

//some fields are not added to avoid too much code. If there is a need for more information I will gladly provide them.

the images below describe the situation:

Image 1: Image is already selected but appears not to be
Image 2: I tapped a field in the form and the image is now seen

[image: Image is already selected but appears not to be]

[image: I tapped a field in the form and the image is now seen]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Form` with `StatefulBuilder` and use its setState to update on bottom Sheet UI.

```dart
 return StatefulBuilder(builder:  (context, setState) {
  return Form(child:  
},)
```

Comment: please how do I use its setState to update the bottom sheet UI

Comment: I've wrapped Form with StatefulBuilder but the image still not show immediately till I tap a field

Comment: are you refering to the `setPicture()`, if it is outside the `StatefulBuilder` pass its setState and use it there ``setPicture(setState)` , let know me after trying this